# mod (%) of two large numbers without using java.math.BigInteger

Tags: java, algorithm, modulo

I have to multiply two large numbers like x and y and then find the mod of result by p without using `BigInteger`like :

```
public static char[] x = {'1','1','5','7','9','2','0','8','9','2','3','7','3','1','6','1','9','5','4','2','3','5','7','0','9','8','5','0','0','8','6','8','7','9','0','7','8','5','3','2','6','9','9','8','4','6','6','5','6','4','0','5','6','4','0','3','9','4','5','7','5','8','4','0','0','7','9','0','8','8','3','3','7','6','6','4','4','7'};
public static char[] y = {'1','1','5','7','9','2','0','8','9','2','3','7','3','1','6','1','9','5','4','2','3','5','7','0','9','8','5','0','0','8','6','8','7','9','0','7','8','5','3','2','6','9','9','8','4','6','6','5','6','4','0','5','6','4','0','3','9','4','4','3','7','4','8','7','3','8','7','4','7','3','1','9','0','6','9','7','4','3'};
public static char[] p = {'1','1','5','7','9','2','0','8','9','2','3','7','3','1','6','1','9','5','4','2','3','5','7','0','9','8','5','0','0','8','6','8','7','9','0','7','8','5','3','2','6','9','9','8','4','6','6','5','6','4','0','5','6','4','0','3','9','4','5','7','5','8','4','0','0','7','9','0','8','8','3','4','6','7','1','6','6','3'};
```

I find out how to multiply x and y but I don't know how to compute mod of two large numbers
Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division

Comment: … and [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: you could make the numbers binary by using mod 2 and then using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier. Do you see how the number only shift by multiplying this way? Now I believe that modulo in binary is XOR operator

Comment: I am new in java and I can't realize which part about my problem. is there any simple way or code to guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Can you compare x and y?

If you can compare them, you can easily implement mod algorithm.

Pseudo Code

```
function mod(a , b) {
    while( a > b ) { a = a - b; }
    return a;
}
```

I dont know java, this is just pseudo code for algorithm.
But if you have implemented subtract and compare functions, you can use them here.